# I wonder how I use "ontouchmoved" in cocos2dx 3.0 final...ㅠㅠ

Tags: image, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make the ball drag like arknoid(only left and right) while touching the ball
I use "visual studio express for windows desktop" on window7 version.

Answer (score 0):

please clarify your question a little more, As far as i understand you could do something like this.

```
    auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    listener->onTouchMoved = [&](cocos2d::Touch* touch, cocos2d::Event* event) {
    auto target = static_cast<Sprite*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
    auto locationInNode = target->convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation());

    ball->setPosition(locationInNode.x);
    };

    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, this);
```